# Android Studio isn't working

Tags: android-studio, 23.04

Installed using the correct repository, when I click on the icon, the program just does not open itself. Tried with both snap and apt version. I have installed the latest openjdk release. What can I do?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To get a better understanding of any error messages that are getting generated, try running the application from the command line, and edit your question to include the output from the messages generated. This will help to provide some additional context around your issue. Thanks

Comment: the "android-studio" command in the terminal shows the message: command not found, with the snap version instead  I can execute the command, but it opens only using sudo, and it runs in rooted mode, and it's not what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using Flathub version. It just works. Snaps and Apt failed once again.